# Как найти элемент id и проверить есть ли он в документе?

Tags: javascript

Как найти элемент id  и проверить есть ли он в документе?

html

```
<div id="mama"> </div>
```

js

```
if(document.getElementById('mama')== true){ 
    alert ("Слово");
}
```

Напридумывал по-моему, а как правильно?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В правильном направлении думал, но проверка на `null` должна идти!

```
if(document.getElementById('mama')!= null){ 
    alert ("Слово");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле хватит и такой проверки, которая и вернет true или false:

```
if(document.getElementById('mama')) {
 alert('true)
}
```

Comment: Код нерабочий, синтаксическая ошибка во второй строке. И вернет не "true или false", а найденный элемент или `null`, если элемент не был найден. Но в целом да, такой проверки тоже хватит.